# remove button is removing all notes except the very specific note

Tags: jquery, html

If I have 3 buttons on the screen that when each is clicked, it loads a note with a remove button. Sometimes, I face the issue of the remove button removing all 3 images, instead of only that specific image. Any ideas why? I have updated the code to each have a different "input#"
but I still get that issue.

```js
$("#addnote3").click(function() {
   
     if($("#theImgb").length == 0){
var txt_box2='<div id="input3" style="display:block"; ><a href=""><img id="theImgb" width="120px;" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/7/9/Z/g/3/blue-red-sticky-note-md.png"/><img src="http://www.pedagogic.com/services/Pics/delete_button_small.gif" class="removec"/></div>';    
     $(".panel1").append($(txt_box2).clone());
        
 $('.panel1').on("click", ".removec", function() {  
     $(".alert").show();
 
    $(this).parent().slideUp('medium',function(e){
$("#input3").remove().empty();
        $(this).remove();
        store();
           $('[input3]').each(function () {
 
        var ids = $('[input3="' + this.id + '"]');
 
        // remove duplicate IDs
        if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) $('#' + this.id).remove();
 
    });
  
    });
});
store();
         }           
    
 });
 
$("#addnote4").click(function() {
      $(".alert").show();
     if($("#theImgb").length == 0){
var txt_box2='<div id="input3" style="display:block"; ><a href=""><img id="theImgc" width="120px;" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/7/9/Z/g/3/blue-red-sticky-note-md.png"/><img src="http://www.pedagogic.com/services/Pics/delete_button_small.gif" class="removec"/></div>';    
     $(".panel1").append($(txt_box2).clone());
        
 $('.panel1').on("click", ".removec", function() {  
     $(".alert").show();
 
    $(this).parent().slideUp('medium',function(e){
$("#input4").remove().empty();
        $(this).remove();
        store();
           $('[input4]').each(function () {
 
        var ids = $('[input4="' + this.id + '"]');
 
        // remove duplicate IDs
        if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) $('#' + this.id).remove();
 
    });
  
    });
});
store();
         }           
    
 });

$("#addnote5").click(function() {
      $(".alert").show();
     if($("#theImgb").length == 0){
var txt_box2='<div id="input5" style="display:block"; ><a href=""><img id="theImgc" width="120px;" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/7/9/Z/g/3/blue-red-sticky-note-md.png"/><img src="http://www.pedagogic.com/services/Pics/delete_button_small.gif" class="removec"/></div>';    
     $(".panel1").append($(txt_box2).clone());
        
 $('.panel1').on("click", ".removec", function() {  
     $(".alert").show();
 
    $(this).parent().slideUp('medium',function(e){
$("#input5").remove().empty();
        $(this).remove();
        store();
           $('[input5]').each(function () {
 
        var ids = $('[input5="' + this.id + '"]');
 
        // remove duplicate IDs
        if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) $('#' + this.id).remove();
 
    });
  
    });
});
store();
         }           
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addnote3">Add</button>
<button id="addnote4">Add</button>
 <button id="addnote5">Add</button>
<div class="panel1"></div>
```

I have these notes that are being appended to the DOM. The notes (addNote 3 and addNote4 ) have a remove button that is attached. Well, I added code in there that will remove that very note that has been attached, but the issue is sometimes it removes everything. (Note the code for that will remove duplicate IDs. I added in this code because in the dom, but no visually the extra IDs were being created, but not visually, so I found that code to remove them.). Any help would be great!

```
$("#addnote3").click(function () {
    $(".alert").show();
    if ($("#theImgb").length == 0) {
        var txt_box2 = '<div id="input3" style="display:block"; ><a href=""><img id="theImgb" width="120px;" src="assets/img/bluesticky3.png"/><img src="assets/img/remove.png" class="removec"/></div>';
        $(".panel1").append($(txt_box2).clone());

        $('.panel1').on("click", ".removec", function () {
            $(".alert").show();

            $(this).parent().slideUp('medium', function (e) {
                $("#input3").remove().empty();
                $(this).remove();
                store();
                $('[input3]').each(function () {

                    var ids = $('[input3="' + this.id + '"]');

                    // remove duplicate IDs
                    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) $('#' + this.id).remove();

                });

            });
        });
        store();
    }

});

$("#addnote4").click(function () {
    $(".alert").show();
    if ($("#theImgb").length == 0) {
        var txt_box2 = '<div id="input3" style="display:block"; ><a href=""><img id="theImgc" width="120px;" src="assets/img/bluesticky4.png"/><img src="assets/img/remove.png" class="removec"/></div>';
        $(".panel1").append($(txt_box2).clone());

        $('.panel1').on("click", ".removec", function () {
            $(".alert").show();

            $(this).parent().slideUp('medium', function (e) {
                $("#input3").remove().empty();
                $(this).remove();
                store();
                $('[input3]').each(function () {

                    var ids = $('[input3="' + this.id + '"]');

                    // remove duplicate IDs
                    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) $('#' + this.id).remove();

                });

            });
        });
        store();
    }

});
```

Comment: No DOM elements should have the same Ids. In your #addnote4 click event you add a div with the same id as the click event does above

Comment: its hard for anyone to help you when your code is doing so much. You should split this up into separate functions/event handlers

Comment: You should refactor this code. Lots of uneaded repitition.

Comment: Provide some HTML that goes with this code.

Comment: I have added some html @dingo_d

Comment: Also, the code to remove extra ids is added because the ID's were being duplicated in the DOM. So this code removes any duplicates.